# localhost redirect to www.localhost.com

Tags: php, redirect, wamp

**Problem:** I tried to install magento into my localhost, but when tried to access the url `localhost/magento` its automatic redirect to `www.localhost.com/magento`. and this problem is just with magento.

After getting this error i tried to install wordpress to confirm that the problem deeper, but wordpress working perfectly, even all the other installed CMS working perfectly rather then magento.

Can anyone please help me, cause i didn't installed anything, and in my office i install magento on wamp without any redirection or error, but don't know what happen in this system..

Comment: Its likely that magento is doing the redirect themselves. You should look at the configuration to see if its something that can be disabled. I should add wordpress does a similar thing, but it matches the domain its installed on it.

Comment: @datasage i downloaded latest version from the site, but don't know on which file i have to check.

Comment: There should be a configuration file of some sort. You may want to check documentation for magento as well.

Comment: Magento generally do this. You need to create a virtual host to run your magento site. Check this http://serverfault.com/questions/119729/how-can-i-avoid-my-web-browser-from-redirecting-to-localhost-using-wamp-in-windo

Comment: @Rikesh i tried with the given link but not helpful :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete file `app/etc/local.xml`
2. Re-install through your IP or domain + `/magento/install.php`.

Then your localhost will jump to your IP or domain and others can visit your website successfully.